# Ruby: module problem

Tags: ruby

cat module1.rb :

```
#!/home/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby

Module module1

    def add(a,b)
        return a+b
    end

    def subtract(a,b)
        return a-b
    end

end


temp = "nothing"
temp.extend module1
temp.add(5,2)
```

ruby module1.rb =>

```
module1.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

Can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 11):

`module` keyword is case-sensitive, and, as Ray said, module must be a constant (constant name in Ruby  starts with uppercase letter). This works:

```
module Module1

    def add(a,b)
        return a+b
    end

    def subtract(a,b)
        return a-b
    end

end


temp = "nothing"
temp.extend Module1
temp.add(5,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a lowercase m to start it all off.

Oh and the module name should be a constant....

Start with

```
module Module1
```

Comment: I changed it from Module to module,  module1.rb:3: class/module name must be CONSTANT

Comment: Yes I added that to my answer already.  vderyagin gave the full answer.